# Llenar un array de char con un string sin contabilizar espacios

Tags: java

Mi objetivo es crear un programa que me contabilice coincidencias introduciendo esta por teclado, el problema es que no consigo que me contabilice las que están más allá del primer espacio, aquí os dejo lo que escribí:

```
public class CuentaCaracteres {

    static void toma(String cadena){
        System.out.print(cadena);
    }

    static String lectura(){
        String palabra;
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        return palabra=leer.next();
    }

    static char lecturaC(){
        char buscar;
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        return buscar=leer.next().charAt(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String palabra="";
        char buscar='b';
        int coincidencia=0;

        System.out.println("Dime una palabra, te contabilizare el numero de coincidencias");
        palabra=lectura();

        char[]caracteres= palabra.replaceAll("\\W ","" ).toCharArray();   

        System.out.println("elemento a buscar");
        buscar=lecturaC();
        for(int i=0; i<caracteres.length;i++){
            if(caracteres[i]==buscar) coincidencia++;
                System.out.println(caracteres[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("Hay " + coincidencia + " coincidencias en el vector");
        }    
}
```

Comment: Para que haces esto? palabra.replaceAll("\\W ","" ) el resto se ve bien, no debería darte problema aunque tengas espacios.

Comment: Alomejor ponerle una funcion que cuando detecta la primera coincidencia te mida la posicion de la coincidencia y que te haga una busqueda apartir de ahi, y se repita siempre que haya coincidencia, hasta que deje de haberlas y entonces te muestre el numero total

Comment: cuando cojas valores por pantalla cógelos con leer.nextLine(), no sea que el buffer se quede abierto

Comment: El comentario de @PabloSimonDiEstefano es tu respuesta amigo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La expresión regular que utilizas ("\\W+ ", "") lo que está haciendo es buscar todas las palabras seguidas por un espacio, y eliminarlas (tanto la palabra como el espacio).

Quizás, una mejor expresión sería que busques todos los tipos de espacios, independiente de su longitud, y los elimines, quedando como resultado una cadena de sólo caracteres sin espacios.

Por ejemplo:

`char[] caracteres = leer.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toCharArray();`

EDITO: Como acabo de leer en algunos comentarios, realmente no te haría falta eliminar los espacios para encontrar coincidencias en el bucle.

Comment: `\W` no coincide con palabras, justamente lo contrario, coincide con caracteres que **no son de palabra**. De esta forma el autor está eliminando todos los caracteres que no sean `[0-9_A-Za-z]` seguidos por un espacio.

Comment: Cierto, no me he dado cuenta de que en mayúsculas significa lo contrario.